# apache ProxyPassReverseCookiePath not work with remote cookie

Tags: apache, cookies

i want replicate in local one webapp and use my rest service in remote. After login the remote server **domainB.com** create some cookie with:

Domain: domainB.com
Path: /

in my apache server i have create this vhost, but i can use remote rest service, but without cookie. **how can I do??**

```
    Define myhost myapp-webapp
    Define hostextension localhost
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ${myhost}@${hostextension}
    ServerName  ${myhost}.${hostextension}
    ServerAlias www.${myhost}.${hostextension} 

    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/myapp/webapp

    #index.localhost.html è utile per le applicazione sencha su cui si vuole fare il bypass del cmd watch
    DirectoryIndex index.localhost.html index.php index.html index.htm

    #-------------------- rewrite rest + SSL ----------------------------------

    SSLProxyEngine On


    #https://dominioB.com/myapp-rest
    ProxyPass /myapp-rest https://dominioB.com/myapp-rest
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp-rest https://dominioB.com/myapp-rest

    ProxyPassMatch ^/myapp-rest(|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) https://dominioB.com/myapp-rest/$1



    #COOKIES
    #--------------------------------------
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / https://dominioB.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain http://myapp-webapp.localhost/ https://dominioB.com/

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all              
    </Directory>

    # Ricordarsi di creare la directory
    ErrorLog  C:/wamp/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}.error.log
    CustomLog C:/wamp/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}.access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the real server create Set-Cookie:
xxx="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly. In real remote server all rest comunication have these cookie, but not is the code js get and use.

Set-Cookie:
yyy="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se si cerca di connettersi a un sito che è in https che risponde con la richiesta di "sicurezza" come flag è necessario attiuvare in locale il servizio ssl del vostro vhost locale.

1. create a new certificate key (see tutorial on web) for your apache wamp
2. create a new vhost for work in ssl (port 443)

   ```
   #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   #+++++++++++++++++ domaina.localhost +++++++++++++++++++++
   #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   Define myhost domaina
   Define hostextension localhost
   <VirtualHost *:443>
           ServerAdmin ${myhost}@${hostextension}
           ServerName  ${myhost}.${hostextension}
           ServerAlias www.${myhost}.${hostextension} 

           DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/myapp/webapp

           #index.localhost.html è utile per le applicazione sencha su cui si vuole fare il bypass del cmd watch
           DirectoryIndex index.localhost.html index.php index.html index.htm


           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           #+                                  SSL                                      +
           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           # myapp work with ssl flag and we must send call from a ssl vhost
           # tutorial for install SSL in wamp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH6evGKgy20
           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


           SSLProxyEngine On
           SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/keys/certificate.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/keys/private.key"
           RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           #+                                  COOKIES                                  +
           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           # We must create and resend set-cookie in our rest comunications
           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
           ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain domaina.localhost domainb.com
           RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"


           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           #+                              PROXY PASS                                   +
           #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

           #https://domainb.com/myapp-rest
           ProxyPass /myapp-rest https://domainb.com/myapp-rest
           ProxyPassReverse /myapp-rest https://domainb.com/myapp-rest
           Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
           ProxyPassMatch ^/myapp-rest(|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) https://domainb.com/myapp-rest/$1



           <Directory />
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride All
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all              
           </Directory>

           # Ricordarsi di creare la directory
           ErrorLog  C:/wamp/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}-ssl.error.log
           CustomLog C:/wamp/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}-ssl.access.log combined

   </VirtualHost>
   ```